# How to Register Routes in Nginx

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have Nearly 70 Routes in My Application What i am trying now
the application is running through dockers and the docker provide a port Something like http://localhost:1400
Now I need to register those routes to nginx but the issues is i have to register all the 70 routes individual... But is there any alternative way to register the base route alone (http://localhost:1400/)
if this done i don't want to register each routes manually ? Right

This is what i tries

```
server {

  listen 80;

  server_name your_domain.com;

  

  location / {

    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

  }

}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What do you mean by route? What do you mean by registering manully?